# Can I use NRPT table on Windows Server 2012 R2 to override default DNS server settings for specific domains?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, internal-dns

I have domain-joined Windows Server 2012 R2 that I need to point to a non-default DNS server to resolve names under a certain internal domain not resolvable by AD. Is it possible to use NRPT (Name Resolution Policy Table) in Local Computer Policy for that? I tried to add a rule for "Generic DNS Server" bit it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why not just use Conditional Forwarders to forward DNS queries to the DNS server(s) that host the DNS zone in question?

Comment: @joeqwerty Can I configure Conditional Forwarders w/o accessing the default AD DNS server? I don't have admin access to AD DNS.